# How can I list only nodes that were not found using Cypher?

Tags: cypher, memgraphdb, opencypher, memgraph

I have a list of capital cities. I want to see if I have all of them. How can I see which cities I don't have inside? My query looks like this at the moment:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Captial {name: 'London'})
RETURN n.name
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Captial {name: 'Paris'})
RETURN n.name
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Captial {name: 'Berlin'})
RETURN n.name
UNION
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Captial {name: 'Rome'})
RETURN n.name
```

This doesn't seem elegant and on top of everything as a result I get:

```
London
Paris
Berlin
null
```

To me it means that I don't have Rome in my database. But can the output be `Rome` only, and not list off all cities that are there and `null` for one that isn't there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Memgraph, it could be solved similarly:

```
WITH ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Rome'] AS capitals
UNWIND capitals as capital
OPTIONAL MATCH (c:Capital {name: capital})
WITH capital, c
WHERE c IS NULL
RETURN capital
```

After you define your list and unwind it to get each element, you can use `OPTIONAL MATCH` (we're not using `MATCH` since `OPTIONAL` allows null) to match each item of the list to the `name` property of nodes. If there are no such nodes we return that capital as an output.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know Memgraph, but in Neo4j I would solve it like this:

```
UNWIND ['London', 'Paris', 'Berlin', 'Rome'] AS capital
OPTIONAL MATCH (n:Captial {name: capital})
WITH n, capital WHERE n IS NULL
RETURN capital
```